# In PyParsing, how to specify that a Word is not equal to a given literal?

Tags: python, scrapy, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse APK download pages from http://www.apkmirror.com such as http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/gmail/gmail-7-3-26-152772569-release-release/gmail-7-3-26-152772569-release-android-apk-download/. Usually, the "APK details" section has the following structure:

[image]

where I want to parse "17329196" as `version_code`, "arm" as `architecture`, and "com.skype.m2" as `package`. Sometimes, however, the line with `architecture` is missing as shown below:

[image]

So far, using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) with the selector

```
apk_details = response.xpath('//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]//text()').extract()
```

I've been able extract a list containing the 'lines' shown above. I'm trying to write a function `parse_apk_details` such that the following tests pass:

```
import pytest

def test_parse_apk_details_with_architecture():
    apk_details = [u'Version: 3.0.38_ww (4030038)',
                   u'arm ',
                   u'Package: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps',
                   u'\n',
                   u'2,239 downloads ']

    version_code, architecture, package = parse_apk_details(apk_details)

    assert version_code == 4030038
    assert architecture == "arm"
    assert package == "com.lenovo.anyshare.gps"

@pytest.mark.skip(reason="This does not work yet, because 'Package:' is interpreted by the parser as the architecture.")
def test_parse_apk_details_without_architecture():
    apk_details = [u'Version: 3.0.38_ww (4030038)',
                   u'Package: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps',
                   u'\n',
                   u'2,239 downloads ']

    version_code, architecture, package = parse_apk_details(apk_details)

    assert version_code == 4030038
    assert package == "com.lenovo.anyshare.gps"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

However, as annotated above, the second test does not pass yet. Here is the function so far:

```
from pyparsing import Word, printables, nums, Optional

def parse_apk_details(apk_details):
    apk_details = "\n".join(apk_details)    # The newline character is ignored by PyParsing (by default)
    version_name = Word(printables)         # The version name can consist of all printable, non-whitespace characters
    version_code = Word(nums)               # The version code is expected to be an integer
    architecture = Word(printables)
    package = Word(printables)

    expression = "Version:" + version_name + "(" + version_code("version_code") + ")" + Optional(architecture("architecture")) + "Package:" + package("package")
    result = expression.parseString(apk_details)

    return int(result.get("version_code")), result.get("architecture"), result.get("package")
```

The error I get when I try to run the second test is:

```
ParseException: Expected "Package:" (at char 38), (line:2, col:10)
```

I believe that what is happening is that the work "Package:" is being 'consumed' as the `architecture`. One way to fix this would be to change the line `architecture = Word(printables)` into something like (in pseudo-code) `architecture = Word(printables) + ~"Package:"`, to indicate that it can be anything consisting of printable characters except the word "Package:".

How might I ensure that the `architecture` is only parsed when it is not the specific word `"Package:"`? (I would also be interested in alternative `scrapy`-based solutions to the original problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were really very close with `architecture = Word(printables) + ~Literal("Package:")`.  To do negative lookahead, start with the negation, then the match:

```
architecture = ~Literal("Package:") + Word(printables)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally used a different characteristic of the line containing the architecture (e.g. "arm"): the fact that the architecture is followed by a newline character, if present. I amended the method `parse_apk_details` to the following:

```
from pyparsing import Word, printables, nums, Optional, LineEnd, FollowedBy, Suppress

def parse_apk_details(apk_details):
    apk_details = "\n".join(apk_details)    # The newline character is ignored by PyParsing (by default)
    version_name = Word(printables).setResultsName("version")       # The version name can consist of all printable, non-whitespace characters
    version_code = Word(nums).setResultsName("version_code")                # The version code is expected to be an integer
    architecture = Word(printables).setResultsName("architecture") + Suppress(FollowedBy(LineEnd()))
    package = Word(printables).setResultsName("package")

    expression = "Version:" + version_name + "(" + version_code + ")" + Optional(architecture) + "Package:" + package
    result = expression.parseString(apk_details)

    return int(result.get("version_code")), result.get("architecture"), result.get("package")
```

This makes both tests pass.

Comment: You can use a short-cut form of `setResultsName` - instead of `version_name = Word(printables).setResultsName("version")`, just write `version_name = Word(printables)("version")`.